# Сортировка Шейкера: распараллелить

Tags: c++, алгоритм, mpi

[**Последовательный алгоритм** сортировки Шейкера](http://algorithmlib.org/sort_shik) понятен. Но как быть с параллельным? Не понятно, что должны выполнять каждый из процессорных элементов и какие данные им передавать?

Натолкните, пожалуйста, на мысль.

Comment: А кто вообще сказал, что возможно распараллелить ЛЮБОЙ алгоритм? Это в принципе невозможно. Тут можно использовать алгоритмы, которые изначально имеют массово-параллельный характер. Типа той же сортировки слиянием.

Comment: @gecube, это учебное задание. Распараллелить данную сортировку нужно. На сколько это эффективно - другой вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрите сначала как параллелятся:  
сортировка Квика  
сортировка Пузырька  
и других замечательных людей

Answer (score 2):

Ну первое, что приходит на ум - разбить массив на части и скормить их разным потокам. Результаты от потоков проанализировать (найти среди всех минимальный и максимальный элемент). Далее отправить массивы без найденных минимальных и максимальных элементов снова этим потокам, проанализировать результаты. Ну и так далее...

Comment: Т.е. на каждом шаге становятся на свое место 2 элемента: максимальный и минимальный?  
Почему-то в моих мыслях было - на каждом шаге на своем месте должны оказаться 2*кол-во_пэ элементов, но высплывало много "но".

Comment: Отсортировать заданным алгоритмом 2 половины массива и выполнить их слияние. Этого в учебных целях достаточно